# Using AJAX/Jquery with custom ASP.NET web controls that call a web-service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, wcf-client

I've written a simple ascx user control called **myLight** that I programtically add several instances of this control to my form.  This control has two buttons **ON** and **OFF**, and it has an "ID" property

I also have a WCF webservice which has two methods **ON** and **OFF** as well as a **Status** function.

So the page will be setup with several instances of **myLight** and each instance will have a unique address.  When the user clicks an ON/OFF button, the appropriate web-service will be called with the address for the control clicked.  However I don't want the entire page to have to reload after each button press, rather just call the web-service.

After I get this part working, I'd like for each control to periodically call the **Status** function with its address so that it can update the color of the control, depending upon the return value.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement this.  AJAX server controls, JQuery, etc.

Comment: First question, does your WCF service live in the same domain as the web site?

Comment: You're doing it the hard way with WCF. For http web services, use [.asmx](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) or [Web API](http://encosia.com/web-api-is-now-part-of-asp-net-and-you-can-get-it-today/).

Comment: @jrummell - I can't believe you actually just suggested that somebody use .asmx

Comment: Yes the service lives in the same domain... and I am actually using an asmx service for this test application

Comment: @Josh believe it. It's dead simple compared to http/WCF. Check out the articles I linked to learn more.

Comment: @jrummell  I've no problem using asmx, which the article linked below references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show you whole concept here is little long and  tedious process so,for implementing ajax enabled wcf service, take a look at following link...

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=235

Comment: This is getting me there.  The only issue I have at this point is that the user controls are all referring to the same javascript.